# How to remove a class with jQuery from all divs not just siblings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, siblings

I'm using jQuery to add a class "selected" to a div when a user clicks on it (it adds a red border to a thumbnail). At the same time I want to remove the class from a previously selected div.

I can get this to work if all the divs are siblings, but other divs in the document remain selected. The page I'm designing and developing requires that the divs can't all be siblings. How can I remove the class "selected" on a previously selected div anywhere in the document, not just the siblings?

You can view and edit my example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3s4dM/6/

**jQuery:**

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.thumbnail {
    background: #dddddd;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnail.selected {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 3px solid #C72D30;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section>

    <div class="thumbnail"></div>

</section>

<section>

    <div class="thumbnail"></div>

</section>

<section>

    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. You can see the work in progress here: http://www.tenbluedevils.com/esalon/tinted-love/product-detail-tinted-love.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combined selector to get all `div` elements with the classes `thumbnail` and `selected` then remove the `selected` class from it.(Since you are again adding `selected` to current thumbnail ignore that also using `not()`)

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $('.thumbnail.selected').not(this).removeClass("selected")
    $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gF2P2/)

Comment: Thanks! That works great. Much appreciated. The other suggestions work well too, but I prefer using `.not()` and the combined selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove class `selected` from all current elements that has `.selected` and add class `selected` to clicked `.thumnail` element:

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function () {
    $('.selected').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s4dM/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there all div's you can do it like this.

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $('div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: This works for this example, but probably isn't a good practice in general--especially since "selected" is such a reusable class.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I suppose that makes this answer better than the others then by technicality!